# Disalignment of Chapter Page Numbers in TOC in LaTex

Tags: latex

In this MWE the page numbers of the chapters in the TOC are shifted slightly to the right from chapter 2 onwards.
I like the format of the chapter headings, but it would not be a problem if they were formatted differently in the table of contents.

How can I fix the problem?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
fontsize=13pt,
paper=A4,
DIV=calc,
headsepline,
plainheadsepline,
numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill}


\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{url}




\usepackage{blindtext} 

\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1} \fontseries{#2} \fontshape{#3} \selectfont}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearscrheadfoot

\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}


\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{setspace} 

\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings} 

\begin{document}

\changefont{cmr}{m}{n} %computer modern %allgemeine Schriftart

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\changefont{cmr}{m}{sc}}

\newpage
\singlespacing

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers will be aligned if you remove all the additional spaces you introduce with your `\changefont` macro:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,
fontsize=13pt,
paper=A4,
DIV=calc,
headsepline,
plainheadsepline,
numbers=noenddot
]{scrreprt}


\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
\KOMAoptions{toc=chapterentrydotfill}


\usepackage[left=3cm,right=2cm,bottom=3cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false, pdfborder={0 0 0}]{hyperref} 
\usepackage{url}




\usepackage{blindtext} 

\newcommand{\changefont}[3]{\fontfamily{#1}\fontseries{#2}\fontshape{#3}\selectfont}

\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearscrheadfoot

\ohead[\pagemark]{\pagemark}


\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\usepackage{setspace} 

\renewcommand{\chapterpagestyle}{scrheadings} 

\begin{document}

\changefont{cmr}{m}{n} %computer modern %allgemeine Schriftart

\setkomafont{sectioning}{\normalcolor\changefont{cmr}{m}{sc}}

\newpage
\singlespacing

\tableofcontents
\newpage

\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument
\Blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]